# Distribution of linear congruential generator with uniform prime modulus

Tags: random, probability

A Linear Congruential Generator is an algorithm yielding a pseudo-random sequence defined by the recurrence

X<sub>n+1</sub> = (X<sub>n</sub>*a + c ) mod q

Under certain conditions (i.e. values for a,c,q,X<sub>0</sub>), the sequence satisfies the frequency test: in any sub-sequence of length L (with L big enough) the number of elements smaller than a given k < q is roughly (k/q)*L.

Is there a formal proof of this fact when the modulo q is a prime number chosen uniformly from some (big) interval? Otherwise stated: if q is a uniform random prime and k <= q, does

P(X<sub>n</sub> < k) = k/q

hold (for opportune values of a,c,X<sub>0</sub>)?

Comment: Wrong forum, I would venture. CrossValidated, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

(It would have been nice to read something about the origin/motivation of this question.)

According to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator), you got a **mixed congruential generator** (if we allow `c` to be nonzero.)

The Hull-Dobell theorem says (careful; different variable names):

`The period of a general mixed congruential generator is at most m, and for some choices of factor a much less than that. The mixed congruential generator will have a full period for all seed values if and only if:`

- `m and c are relatively prime`
- `a-1 is divisible by all prime factors of m`
- `a-1 is divisible by 4 if m is divisible by 4`

What does this tell us?

- The most important thing is the **if and only if** (<-> equivalence relation)

  - If i understood you correctly, you are asking about the randomness if the modulo-value (above: `m`) is given by some method
  - The theorem above tells us, that for each chosing of `m`, there exist a `c`, so that the RNG will not have a full period (a number which is not relatively prime)!
  - Not having a full period will break your frequency-test
  - **Implication: Information about the modulo-number/m alone is not enough to reason about randomness (in general; as for each chosing of m, there is a c which will break the full-period!)**

The above is not formal but should give you an idea for further analysis!

Comment: This question origins from an algorithmic application: I needed to study some randomness properties of Karp-Rabin fingerprinting (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin–Karp_algorithm), and realized that the karp-rabin fingerprints of text prefixes resemble sequences generated with LCG. 

Thanks for the answer! I was aware of the result you mentioned, I am now trying to apply it to the problem.